# Can I connect to websocket through network IP Address?

Tags: iis, websocket, lan

I am having problem connecting to websocket through IP Address. I can connect to websocket through WAN url "ws://dev.mysite.com/WSockets/WSHttpHandler.ashx". But unable to connect with LAN url "ws://192.168.1.23/MySite/WSockets/WSHttpHandler.ashx".

Error is "Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500"

"http://dev.mysite.com" and "http://192.168.1.23/MySite" are the same as our site was hosted on own server (windows server 2012) IIS.

My Question is, is it possible to connect to websocket through server IP Address? If it can, what could be my problem?

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The point that the websocket handshake protocol is actually HTTP. So, just like your virtual HTTP domain, your web server is set up to handle requests for dev.mysite.com differently from one for other domains.

Hence, your IP address is not equivalent to your domain name in a URL -- remember: A URL specifies a *unique location*, which means that domain names and IP addresses need not be exchangeable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I still don't know what was I missing.

I just setup a forward lookup zone, "sample.mysite.com", in my DNS and point to my desired IP Address, 192.168.1.23.
Now I can browse my site "http://192.168.1.23/MySite" as "http://sample.mysite.com". 
Then, I tried to connect to my socket as "ws://sample.mysite.com/WSockets/WSHttpHandler.ashx". But still got no luck with the return error "failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200". Please advise.

Thanks.